# Using OR Operator inside count() function in Python

Tags: python, list, count, conditional-operator

I have a list say `x = ['abc','cde','tar','har','yyu']`
I want to count the number of times 'abc' or 'tar' came, what I am trying to find is something like

```
count1 = x.count('abc'or'tar')
print(count1)
```

I want the answer to be 2 but the answer is coming 1. I have searched other codes in Stack Overflow. is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
count1 = x.count('abc') + x.count('tar')
print(count1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`x.count('abc' or 'tar')`  gives you 1 because `'abc' or 'tar' = 'abc'` 
and your search is equal to `x.count('abc')` 
The simplest way is `x.count('abc')+x.count('tar')`

Answer (score 1):

The use of `or` is not what you think... The Pythonic evaluation of `'abc' or 'tar'` is `'abc'`, so your code is effectively the same as:

```
count1 = x.count('abc')
print(count1)
```

To get the sum of both, you have to call the `count()` routine for each string searched for. So you could use:

```
count1 = x.count('abc') + x.count('tar')
print(count1)
```

If you wanted to check for multiple strings, you could do a simple loop like:

```
count = 0
for stringy in ('abc', 'tar',): # and others
    count += x.count(stringy)
print(count)
```

Comment: thank you. but this was an example. what I am trying to do is read from a text file. say (1) 'abc','edf' (2) 'abc','tar'. now 'abc' came 2 times and 'tar' came 1 time. for (2) 'abc' and 'tar' both came so I dont want to double count them. I want to count them once if they both came. so I want my answer here to be 2 but using + operator gives me 3.

Comment: @SataMukherjee - What you're talking about now is logic different than what you posted in your question. I think I have answered your original Q. If you need further assistance, please post a new Q.

Answer (score 0):

`list.count` only accepts a single value as an argument.

```
count(value, /) method of builtins.list instance
    Return number of occurrences of value.
```

You could use the solution provided by @adrtam or You could use the `sum` function with generator expression.

```
>>> x = ['abc','cde','tar','har','yyu']
>>> sum(1 for i in x if i in ('abc', 'tar'))
```